# Maintain checkbox state same after submit page in oracle apex

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle, oracle-apex

I’m working on Oracle Apex.

In the region1 there will be LOV while submit region1 in report2 the interactive report will be shown based upon data through SQL query and I have checkbox in the report2.

But the problem here is: I click the checkbox and then submit page through button. Checkbox' value has been lost after refresh page and I want the checkbox to be the same as what I checked before.

Please, can any body help me in this ?

Thanks

Praveen

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, Interactive **report** is what its name says: a "report" (something you use to *view* data, not *edit* it).

If you want to do it in a simple manner (read: out-of-box, no additional coding in JavaScript or whatever else), switch to an **Interactive Grid** which lets you edit data presented on the screen. Doing so, your checkbox value wouldn't be lost upon submit.

For more info and some examples, have a look at [Add awesome checkboxes and status fields in an Interactive Grid in Oracle APEX](http://dgielis.blogspot.com/2020/09/add-awesome-checkboxes-and-status.html) (by Dimitri Gielis).

---

Can it be done in an interactive report? Yes; there are examples on the Internet (Google for it), such as [Preserving checked checkboxes in a report](https://joelkallman.blogspot.com/2008/03/preserving-checked-checkboxes-in-report.html) (by Joel Kallman), [Report with Checkboxes](https://www.talkapex.com/2015/09/report-with-checkboxes-update/) (by Martin Giffy D'Souza), etc.

Comment: Everything I posted works in Oracle Apex, and there's nothing I'd like to add to what I've already said.